# How to restart Crashlytics session Android Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-fabric, android-log

App contains forms that need to submit to the server. Recenlty one of the customers raise an issue regarding form fields missing.

To catch the missing fields, I implemented log from Fabric. So when the user submits form, generated XML will be logged.

```
 Crashlytics.log(xmlForm);
 Crashlytics.logException(new RuntimeException());
```

Logging is very uncertain. Even not all logs are being added into fabric. 
Don't see the all logs.

[image]

I may chance log size exceed 64 KB on each session for that reason unable find all logs.

Question:
1. As the session log size limit is 64KB, How to could I terminate session explicitly and restart?
2. Is there any log lib. for android?

I am looking for any API/Lib. which can provide logging. I don't want a crash report lib.

I need to log form xml when user submits form.

Comment: You can use slf4j logger with Bugfender.

Comment: @MD Agree, how to use in Android?

Comment: Simple you can implement `bugfender SDK` in your project with `slf4j logger`. Check [this](https://bugfender.com/platforms/android/)

Comment: The order of things that can happen on a users phone is not deterministic, so logs do occasionally get dropped when reported to Fabric.